# How the TEC AND REC actually increments in CAN protocol?

Tags: embedded, protocols, can-bus

I have read the specification from BOSCH but it is very confusing!
Is it like this?

1. A node, which detects an error and sends the ERROR FLAG (whether it is a transmitter or receiver ), will increment its TEC by 8;
2. A node, which receives the ERROR FRAME, will increment its REC by one.

And for example think of a situation where transmitter was transmitting a message and a node is receiving it and suppose the transmitter detects a bit error so it will transmit an ERROR FLAG and the receiving node would detect this as a bit stuff error and transmits another ERROR FLAG.

So in this case here TEC of transmitter should increase by 8 as it detects bit error. And my question is: Will both the TEC and REC of the receiver node get incremented? (Since it receives an ERROR frame and it detects and generate another error frame)

One more question: They are mentioning a situation where the REC gets incremented by 8. What will be that situation, any idea?